# Change colour of highlighting of preview search results (TeXShop)?

Tags: highlighting, preview, search

[image][enter image description here][2][![enter image description here][3]][3]Is it possible to change the highlight colour of search results in the document in the preview window (not in list of search drawer results or in editor window) from very light grey to bright yellow, pink, etc.? I often have to search for 1- or 2-character elements, e.g.,  punctuation, in the preview window when editing. I have changed my background to turquoise and it helped a bit, but I'd really like to find a way to change to true highlighting colours, if there is one. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

[image: preview window]

Comment: I believe the highlight color in the active preview window is the one set in the General Pane of System Preferences. If the preview window is not selected it will show up as grey.

Comment: Hi Herb. I changed the highlight colour in the system preferences to red, which works in my email and other places. It also works in the preview search results list, but not in the actual preview of the document. It is still light grey. Will try to add a screenshot to my question.

Comment: It looks like the pane with display of the pdf file is not active. Click on that pane to activate it. There is another way to do a search in the preview window. Click on the >> at the right side of the toolbar and see if there is a search box there. If so you can close the tray and use that for searching. If it’s not there you can add it by Ctl-Clicking on the toolbar, choose Customize Toolbar and add it where you wish. You can also place it in a desirable position in the toolbar.

Comment: Success! Using the "search PDF" box results in red highlighting in the PDF. At my end, the search PDF function requires I click on the little magnifing glass each time to get to the subsequent instances of the word, rather than using the keyboard (hitting enter key). Are you aware of a setting to change this? Also, I wasn't able to get the grey highlighting to change to red for results in the PDF preview window when I use the tray/drawer search function. At least I now have the search PDF option for when I'm looking for short strings of things. Thank you so much!

Comment: Use Cmd-G to go to the next match.

Comment: PS: the reason it's grey when you use the side panel is that when you do that search the list of finds is selected (and therefore you see a red highlight). If you click on the pdf pane I suspect that list pane will have a grey highlight and the selection in the pdf pane will be red.

Comment: Unfortunately the grey doesn't change to red in the PDF preview. The red highlighting in the list of finds does go from red to grey when I click on the PDF but then the grey highlighting on the word in the PDF disappears altogether (i.e., even if the PDF preview window is selected/active).

Comment: I am having the same problem.  If anyone has any solution, I would be very interested!